# how pass parameter with routerLink to ngOnInit of another component

Tags: angular, rxjs

In certain component I have:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/view-transactions', account.id]">View Transactions</a>
```

My app-routing.modules.ts I have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'view-transactions/:accountid', component: TransactionComponent }
```

In my transaction.component.ts I have:

```
transaction: Transaction[];

constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router,
            private location: Location) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.transactionService.getTransactionsByAccountId(+params['id']))
        .subscribe(transaction => this.transaction = transaction);
}
```

Resulting in:

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
>           at y. (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content.min.js:16:421)

[image]

Comment: nowhere i can see options in your code

Comment: @Sajeetharan, sorry, can you explain a bit more? What is options in this context and why should I use? A very simple snippet may clarify

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined , in the code you provided you dont have options anywhere if you are using any extensions of chrome. remove them and try or try in different browser

Comment: @Sajeetharan I added a picture. I am pretty sure I am either passing wrongly the parameter or I am trying to get the value wrongly. But I can sse anything wrong in my code. I can't imagine any issue with Brower itself.

Comment: what is this.idaccount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your param is not `id`. According to your routing configuration your param is called `accountid` and not `id`.

See `{ path: 'view-transactions/:accountid', component: TransactionComponent }`

Therefore try to replace:

```
    this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.transactionService.getTransactionsByAccountId(+params['id']))
    .subscribe(transaction => this.transaction = transaction);
```

with:

```
    this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.transactionService.getTransactionsByAccountId(+params['accountid']))
    .subscribe(transaction => this.transaction = transaction);
```

and it should work.